# Recorded web test performing any operation twice in vsts 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, performance-testing

I am using vsts 2012 and IE 11 for web performance testing of MVC web application.  So I did the following steps:

1. Create web and load project
2. Recorded one web test for "create user" scenario
3. Checked in actual database and on UI whether created user count=1 or not

Here I have not re-run the recorded test but still I can see two users have been created. I have only recorded one test and have not run that test. So I expected the user count to be 1.

Is there any issue with web test recording for first time?

When we run the test a second time then it shows the correct user count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the "stop recording" button for a Visual Studio web test the test is rerun by Visual Studio. You can see some of this happening behind the popup about detecting dynamic parameters. After the that detection has completed and Visual Studio is ready to accept further commands you will see in the **Test Results** window some details of that execution. Often this will show that the test failed, but don't worry about that failure.

For your specific question, I believe that one record was created by you when you recorded the test. The second record was created by the test executed for the purpose of detecting dynamic parameters.

Comment: Yes agree with you ....but i tried it many times ....i have observed the same behavior.....when i start recording and click on stops ...then after detection of dynamic parameter ....i checked on UI and DB ,....there i found two users.....but i have recorded only once ....and its detecting dynamic parameters for same test ...so why two user are getting creating .......If it is default behavior of   vsts web test recorder then ...i am fine with it ....that means i can conclude or give reason to my seniors ....why this ambiguous behavior....

Comment: And if we stopped detection of dynamic parameters then ...it will create only oneuser right??? ...I want to know what it collects while detecting dynamic parameters ....is it compulsory steps ..in web test ??? can we ignore detection of dynamic values ...

Comment: @ClarkMike The test is run twice: once when recording and again when detecting dynamic parameters. There may be an option to avoid detecting dynamic parameters but I do not know where it would be. There is no ambiguous behaviour. It is entirely predictable. It is how Visual Studio works. What is your question?

Comment: Yes i wanted to know this confirmation ....for how test run twice...as u said 1. when recording 2. Detection of dynamic parameters ...if its definitely behavior of vsts then ..there is no problem ...my problem is resolved...thanks...